# What does "(control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} | null =>" do?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to TypeScript and Angular but I have a pretty good background in C#.

I'm reading this [article](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation), specifically "Custom validators" and this snippet

```
export function forbiddenNameValidator(nameRe: RegExp): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} | null => {
    const forbidden = nameRe.test(control.value);
    return forbidden ? {'forbiddenName': {value: control.value}} : null;
  };
}
```

What does this line of code do/mean? Is this TypeScript's way of defining a delegate?

```
(control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} | null => {
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an `arrow function`.  To understand it, you can read it as

```
function (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} | null {
  const forbidden = nameRe.test(control.value);
  return forbidden ? {'forbiddenName': {value: control.value}} : null;
};
```

That is, the function returns type `{[key: string]: any}` (an object with key(s) declared as variable named `key`, and value type can be any), or `null`; while the function requires input value with Angular type `AbstractControl`.

In TypeScript, a colon is frequently used in two ways:

1. In an object, such as `{ key: value }`
2. Define the type of a value, which might be your question in this case.

Hope this helps.  Welcome to the world of Angular & TypeScript!

Comment: Ahh this makes so much more sense now. Thanks

Comment: const forbidden = nameRe.test(control.value);

can I add another forbidden name, inside the code above? like combine them there in one initialization